# TypeScript: Prevent loading @types definition that does not export (TS2306 is not a module)

Tags: node.js, typescript

I've sunken quite some hours into trying to load a NodeJS library, that has a (in my opinion faulty) type definition in the @types repository.

I am talking about [geolib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geolib) and its [@types/geolib](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/geolib/index.d.ts)

*Yes, I am aware, that the library has types on master, but there is no tagged release for it yet and I want to resolve this for future cases.*

## Installing `geolib` (2.0.22 at the time)

- `npm install geolib --save`
- `import * as geolib from 'geolib';`

everything is awesome! but no type resolution in your favorite editor

## Installing `@types/geolib`

- `npm install @types/geolib --save-dev`

Here is where it breaks:

`node_modules/@types/geolib/index.d.ts' is not a module. (2306)`

This is because the types file, does not `export = geolib` but it is tried to load this file as a module.

My goal is to simply load the node library as such and use the `@types/geolib` just as type hints for development.

I have tried multiple options, e.g. using the new `types` directive, preventing the auto loading by setting `types: []` in tsconfig, importing with just `import 'geolib'`, but nothing seems to work around the issue that the definition lies in `@types` and is tried as a module.

### Edit

- `typescript@2.3.4`
- `geolib@2.0.22`
- `@types/geolib@2.0.2`

Comment: Seems like an issue with the type definitions. As a workaround you can try adding a custom `d.ts` file and declare the module yourself with the export.

Comment: Yes it is and I kinda wanted to avoid doing that, as they are there. I just need to prevent them being loaded as a module.

Comment: Same issue here. Did you by any chance solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue.

What worked for me is:

```
import * as GeoLib from 'geolib';
```

and later for example:

```
import * as GeoLib from 'geolib';
import PositionAsDecimal = GeoLib.PositionAsDecimal;

distance += GeoLib.getDistance(pointAPositionAsDecimal, pointBPositionAsDecimal, accuracyInMeters, precision);
```

Comment: Hey Jimmy, the import is not the problem :) this is all about the type definitions in DefinitelyTyped. The master branch of geolib does include correct type definitions, but it has still not been repackaged for a release. So best would be installing the master branch instead of the 2.0.22 tag and get the types with it.

Comment: Check. Did not have that issue.